# could not init postgres with a dump file

Tags: testcontainers

just starting testcontainers. I love the idea. thanks for investing in this project.

I am trying to create a simple postgres 14.5 container (and susceeded) and now I am trying to populate it using the .withInitScript() method.

the file I am feeding into the init method is a dump I created with pg_dumpall.

testcontainers fails for many parsing/validation reasons. each time I delete a portion and another reason pops up.

should I be able to succesfully use the withInitScript with pg_dump files?

BTW, using pg_dump for my main DB also has many similar issues.

thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by `BTW, using pg_dump for my main DB also has many similar issues.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try copying the script to the container so postgres will execute. Although this comment `BTW, using pg_dump for my main DB also has many similar issues.` makes me wonder if it will work because it also fails when you are using the database directly if I understood correctly.

```java
new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:14.5")
                    .withCopyFileToContainer(
                        MountableFile.forClasspathResource("init.sql"), 
                        "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"
                     );
```

We recommend to use [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) or [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) to manage database changes.

Comment: So don't use `.withInitScript()`, but the mechanism described in the docs of the official image (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) or a dedicated tool such as liquibase or Flyway.